# How to store an inner nested hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, store, storable

I have a perl nested hash. When I try to store using Storable module, the inner hash, I'm getting the error "not a reference".
Example:

```
store($outer_hash->{$id}, $filename);
```

And how should I retrieve it back?
Is the next line is the right way?

```
$outer_hash->{$id} = retrieve($filename);
```

Comment: The question is: are you sure that `$outer_hash->{$id}` is an hash reference?

Comment: You don't have an inner hash as you claim you have

Comment: Thanks, indeed It wasn't.